# Fore each user get total spend amount

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So in my mongo database I have a lot of records for each user which look similar to this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("563d32e1f91e50523787ad2c"), "userId" : ObjectId("563cedfb86aa990cf500000d"), "price" : NumberLong(200)}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("563d32eaf91e50523787adb6"), "userId" : ObjectId("563cedfb86aa990cf500000d"), "price" : NumberLong(500)}
```

What I need to achieve is to get sum of price field for each user.
BTW I have around 1 million users and around 2-8 records for price.

How shell query for this would look a like ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute sum of a field group by `userId` with an `aggregate` :

```
db.device.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        "_id": "$userId",
        "totalAmount": { $sum: "$price"}
    }
}])
```

Check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/